# If 2 spaceship fly in opposit directions at 99.9% of speed of light what is the distance between them would be in ...?

Tags: special-relativity

2 ship fly in opposite directions from each other each one at the 99.9% speed of light relative to the zero point. I assume that at the zero point time in 1 seconds the ship will be 2 light seconds away from each other, but in their local time after 1 second they will be 1 light second away from each other, this looks like a contradiction, because the local time at the ships will tick slowly compared to the zero point time, so they have got to be much farther from each other in 1 second of their local time. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have considered time dilation but you didn't consider length contraction.

And for spaceship B relative velocity of spaceship A will be given by

$\vec{v}_{\text{a|b}}=\frac{|\vec{v}_{\text{a}}-\vec{v}_{\text{b}}|}{1-\frac{\vec{v}_{\text{a}}\vec{v}_{\text{b}}}{c²}}$

So distance travelled by spaceship A wrt will be 0.999% of c in 1 sec and vice versa.